# How to compare records from two text files and then print the entire line from both files if match is found in python

Tags: python-3.x

> I have two text files. FIle1 contains:

```
id int| name varchar(10)
1     |Joey
2     |Monica
3     |Rachel
```

> File 2 conatins:

```
 employeeID int   | productID int
    1             |344
    1             |355
    2             |544
```

> I want to print on the console, the records that match the ID from the file1 with the EmployeeID from the File2

```
1|Joey  |1|344
1|Joey  |1|355
2|Monica|2|544
```

> I have tried something like this,

```
with open(file1,'rt') as f1:
    with open(file2,'rt') as f2:
        for lines in f1:
            for line in f2:
                lines1=lines.split('|')
                v1=lines1[0]

                line2=line.strip('\n')
                v2=line2[0]


                if (v1==v2):
                    content=lines.strip('\n')+'|'+str(line)
                    print(content.strip('\n'))
                else:
                    pass
```

> But this just gives output as null. When I remove the headers of both the files, it gives me below output.

```
1|Joey|1|344
1|Joey|1|355
```

> Somehow the first for loop is not iterating over the all lines.
>   can someone please help